# How to store int and string value in bean class?

Tags: java, javabeans

I know this is very basic question yet I am unable to get the perfect answer. I have one bean named `Order` in which there is one object `product_size` such as

```
public Class Order{
      private String product_size;
}
```

Setter and Getter methods are defined respectively in that class. The problem is that `product_size` may contain `string variable` such as `S` or `Integer value` such as `7`.

I am unable to store the Integer value in that bean object.

Comment: I think you need to always store it as a String

Comment: in setter, before storing the variable, loop through the word if it contains other than character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done with only one bean instance and I am check that if value is string it should be added in bean object Simply else `Integer.toString()` method will convert the int value to String.

Example is given below-

```
String str;      // it is dynamic let there are two values in this 'S' and 8
if (str instancof String){
   order.setProduct_Size(str);
}else{
  order.setProduct_Size(Integer.toString(str));
}
```